Typeorm table temporary doesn't exist
I'm create table temporary and set data via call to a stored procedure in MySQL.
This is my stored procedure:
CREATE DEFINER=`localhost`@`%` PROCEDURE `db_example`.`generate_series`(_start VARCHAR(20), _stop VARCHAR(20), _step VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    -- establish range type being produced 
    -- establish step increment
    -- call appropriate generation function
    DECLARE _typecheck VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE _interval  VARCHAR(20);
    -- we don't know the type of these vars till runtime
    SET @START = @STOP = @step = NULL;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS series_tmp;

    -- All parameters are required
    IF LENGTH(CAST(_start AS UNSIGNED) + 0) = LENGTH(_start) THEN
        SET _typecheck = 'INTEGER';
        SET @START = CAST(_start AS UNSIGNED);
        SET @STOP  = CAST(_stop AS UNSIGNED);
        SET @step  = CAST(_step AS UNSIGNED);
    ELSE
        SET _typecheck = 'DATETIME';
  
    IF LENGTH(_start) = 10 THEN
        SET @START = CAST(_start AS DATE);
        SET @STOP  = CAST(_stop AS DATE);
    ELSE
        SET @START = CAST(_start AS DATETIME);
        SET @STOP  = CAST(_stop AS DATETIME);
    END IF;

    IF _step REGEXP 'INTERVAL [0-9]+ (SECOND|MINUTE|HOUR|DAY|WEEK|MONTH|YEAR)' = 1 THEN
       SET _interval = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_step, ' ', -1); 
       SET @step = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_step, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED);
     ELSE
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '\'step\' parameter should be in the form INTERVAL n SECOND|MINUTE|HOUR|DAY|WEEK|MONTH|YEAR';
    END IF;
  END IF;
  IF _typecheck = 'INTEGER' THEN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE series_tmp (
      series BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
    WHILE @START <= @STOP DO
      -- Insert in tmp table
      INSERT INTO series_tmp (series) VALUES (@START);
      -- Increment value by step
      SET @START = @START + @step;
    END WHILE;
  ELSE
    IF LENGTH(@START) = 10 THEN
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE series_tmp(
        series DATE PRIMARY KEY
      ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
    ELSE
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE series_tmp(
        series DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
      ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
    END IF;
    WHILE @START <= @STOP DO
      INSERT INTO series_tmp (series) VALUES (@START);
      CASE UPPER(_interval)
        WHEN 'SECOND' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step SECOND);
        WHEN 'MINUTE' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step MINUTE);
        WHEN 'HOUR' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step HOUR);
        WHEN 'DAY' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step DAY);
        WHEN 'WEEK' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step WEEK);
        WHEN 'MONTH' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step MONTH);
        WHEN 'YEAR' THEN
          SET @START = DATE_ADD(@START, INTERVAL @step YEAR);
        END CASE;
     END WHILE;
  END IF;
END

This is my code in nextJs using typeorm:
const queryRunner = this.dyndsSvc.getDataSource();

//generate table temporary via storage procedure
await queryRunner.query('CALL generate_series(?, ?, ?)', [
  startDate,
  endDate,
  `INTERVAL ${interval} MINUTE`,
]);

// select data from table temporary
const movements = await queryRunner.query(
  "SELECT DATE_FORMAT((st.series + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), '%H:%i') AS timeslice FROM series_temp st",
);

but table temporary series_temp doesn't exist. How to fix it?
I'm read from the other question and the answer:

Temporary tables only exist during the connection. If you create it with one query and then do a separate query on a new connection it is already gone.

